VectorStoreIndex API Key while using AzureOpenAI Service
I'm trying to use VectorStoreIndex from llama_index solving the RAG problem for chatbot just the following way:
import openai
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(docs)
index.storage_context.persist()

When I read documentation, it is recommended to use openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY') to be able to connect model with OpenAI. But what should I do if I use AzureOpenAI (meaning, that I have api_key, azure_endpoint and api_version and don't have openai api_key)? If I use openai.api_key = my_azure_api_key this also does not work because apparently the model refers to https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys and not to AzureAI Services..
Sorry if the question looks dubious, was unable to find the information on web.
Thanks!

I believe you're looking at outdated docs, or the wrong documentation entirely. Have you read through any of the quickstarts on Microsoft's site? There's plenty of Python sample code that shows exactly how you'd accomplish this specifically using the Azure OpenAI Serivce (and not OpenAI's own endpoints) with the authentication values you have in your possession.

Checked that already. There was 0 information about llama-index obviously..

Have solved it. Actually all you need is to add context parameter into VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(). In this parameter one can specify AzureOpenAI or AzureOpenAIEmbedding and obviously use api_key, azure_endpoint and api_version.
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)

